# How to update Electron browser window frame border thickness?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, windows-style-flags

I have one react electron app installed.
I want to increase the border thickness of main browser window not the app.
If I created frameless window like this:

```
 mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    frame: false
  });
```

then I can apply border to html or body section.

But I want to increase the border thickness of actual window(having frame) not the body or html.
According to the electron docs https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window:
**thickFrame** Boolean (optional) - Use **WS_THICKFRAME** style for frameless windows on Windows, which adds standard window frame. Setting it to false will remove window shadow and window animations. Default is true.

If anyone knows how to apply windows style then please help.

Comment: `WS_THICKFRAME` is there?